# Why isn't the ++y part executing?

Tags: c++, if-statement, post-increment, logical-and

So here is the question I am given , I need to tell the output :

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int x = 10;
    int y = 20;
    if(x++ > 10 && ++y > 20 ){
    cout << "Inside if ";
    } else{
    cout << "Inside else ";
    }
    cout << x << “ “ << y;
}
```

The ans given is `Inside else 11 20` I checked with complier this is the correct answer but according to me the answer should be `Inside else 11 21`.

Why is this happening ? Why isn't the ++y part executing ?

I also tried y++ I still get same answer.

Comment: have you tried ++x

Comment: Short circuit evaluation. That is how both && and || are required to work in C++.

Comment: ***Why isn't the ++y part executing?*** Because (x++ > 10)  is not true

Comment: @drescherjmthen if I change it to ++x why does it work

Comment: Because `++x` increments before the comparison and not after. `x++` increments after. (++x > 10) is evaluated as  (11 > 10) while (x++ > 10) is evaluated as (10 > 10)

Comment: "if I change it to ++x why does it work" because `x++ > 10` is false but `++x > 10` is true

Comment: Ah i finally got it thx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the first operand of the logical AND (`&&`) operator evaluates to false, the second operand is not evaluated, because the value of the expression is already known.

From the C++ 20 Standard (7.6.14 Logical AND operator)

> 1 The && operator groups left-to-right. The operands are both contextually converted to bool (7.3). The result is true if both operands are true and false otherwise. Unlike &, && guarantees left-to-right evaluation: **the second operand is not evaluated if the first operand is false**.

Also, the value of an expression with the post-increment operator is the value of its operand *before* incrementing.

From the C++ 20 Standard (7.6.1.6 Increment and decrement_

> 1 The value of a postfix ++ expression is the value of its operand...

So, in this `if` statement:

```
if(x++ > 10 && ++y > 20 ){
```

the left operand of the logical AND operator `x++ > 10` evaluates to `false`. However, the side effect of the post-increment operator is applied to the variable `x`. The second operand `++y > 20` is not evaluated.

So, the control will be passed to the `else` statement, and within its sub-statement `x` will be equal to `11` and `y` will keep its original value `20`.

Answer (score 7):

When you write `x++`, that means two things:

- return *current* value
- increment `x`

Since current value is `10` and `10 > 10` is false, the part after `&&`, including `++y`, is not evaluated.

An alternative would be prefix increment, i.e., `++x`.